# A matrix with more than $m$ columns may have more than one set of $m$-dimensional vectors with $m$ mutually linearly independent columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Chapter 2.4 (Linear Dependence and Span), page 36 of *Deep Learning* by Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville, claims the following:

> No set of $m$-dimensional vectors can have more than $m$ mutually linearly independent columns, but a matrix with more than $m$ columns may have more than one such set.

I understand that no set of $m$-dimensional vectors can have more than $m$ mutually linearly independent columns, but I'm unsure of what the latter claim is trying to say.

It's probably the way that this is phrased that is confusing me, so I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: A $4x8$ matrix may have many sets of $4$ linearly independent columns.  Perhaps the first $4$ columns are independent, and so are the last $4$ columns.

Comment: @saulspatz Ahh, I understand now. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @saulspatz: That seems like an answer to me. (I think we have too many comments that are answers, which prevents questions from being marked as answered.)

Comment: @joriki Point taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 4x8 matrix may have many sets of 4 linearly independent columns. Perhaps the first 4 columns are independent, and so are the last 4 columns

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple example: any pair of columns of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ that you choose are linearly independent.